# SQLite exception: no such table, while successfully connecting to DB

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

When I executing the following function, I get the following response:

> Failed to insert data into sqlite table:  no such table: users

```
user_id = uuid.uuid4()
save_record.name = name
save_record.score = score
last_time = datetime.now()

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('OnlineJeopardy.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print("Successfully Connected to OnlineJeopardy DB.")

    sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO users
    (User_id, Name, Score, Last_time) 
    VALUES 
    (?, ?, ?, ?)"""

    add_to_db = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, (user_id, name, score, last_time))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table: ", error)
finally:
    if (conn):
        conn.close()
        print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

When I execute this query in DB Browser, with actual values instead of placeholders, it all goes well.

I've tried swapping placeholders to actual values (as below) within the query in sqlite3 but the outcome was the same.

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('OnlineJeopardy.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print("Successfully Connected to OnlineJeopardy DB.")

    sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO users
    (User_id, Name, Score, Last_time) 
    VALUES 
    ('ID-1337', 'Adam', 20, '2020-06-12 23:18:58')"""

    add_to_db = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Does the database *OnlineJeopardy.db* exist in the same directory as Python script? Remember, if no database exists at the time, `connect` will create it with no tables. Carefully check directories. Consider passing absolute path: `sqlite3.connect('/path/to/OnlineJeopardy.db')`.

Comment: @Parfait it does exist in the same directory, I tried setting up absolute path but that didn't change anything. For the simplicity of the project I put everything into the same folder to avoid having path errors.